# how to find specific string in key value pair in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am having data in mongodb like that

```
[

{
  "name":"silvester",
  "product":"laptop,iphone,mobile,phone"
},

{
   "name":"john",
   "product":"cycle,bus,phone,laptop"
},

{
   "name":"franklin",
   "product":"cycle,phone"
}

]
```

How to find that laptop is in product key.
if product key look like this

```
{
"name":"XXX",
"product":"laptop"
}
```

I can easily find that name by using this `db.collection.find("product":"laptop");`

So how to find this?

Also let me know this three website name running under using  backbone.js and node.js and mongodb technology such as www.trello.com .
sorry for my worst english..

Comment: Is "product" an array or a string or comma separated elements?

Comment: Is the solution posted below not working for you?

Comment: You should store `product` as an array of strings, since Mongo is optimized for this case.  Anything else is going to be much slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using regex with mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/)

This worked for me

db.collection.find({"product": /laptop/})

**Updated Answer**

If you wish to use variables, try something like this:

```
var abc = "laptop";
// other stuff
userdetails.find({"product":new RegExp(abc)}).toArray(function(err,result){
  if (err) console.log ("error: "+err);
  else 
  {    
    // if you want the length
    console.log(result.length);
    // if you actually want to see the results
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
      console.log(result[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

**Updated One More Time**

```
var abc = "laptop";
// other stuff

// note this is case sensitive.  if abc = "Laptop", it will not find it
// to make it case insensitive, you'll need to edit the RegExp constructor
// to this: new RegExp("^"+abc+",|, "+abc+"(?!\w)", "i")

userdetails.find({"product":new RegExp("^"+abc+",|, "+abc+"(?!\w)")}).toArray(function(err,result){
  if (err) console.log ("error: "+err);
  else 
  {    
    // if you want the length
    console.log(result.length);
    // if you actually want to see the results
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
      console.log(result[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I would rather change schema in order to make product field to be an array of strings, which will enable you to use indexes for this field and significantly improve performance of you query. As in current version you are going to walk through entire collection everytime.

Comment: i have given this dynamically like this var abc=laptop; userdetails.find({"product":"/"+abc+"/"}).toArray(function(err,result){console.log(result.length)});     but i have got zero length only so how to do this dynamically?

Comment: i am getting output even if i give l instead of laptop but i want output only when i give exact laptop not l or la or lap

Comment: Please note, this was not actually addressed in the question.  In the future it may be best to create a new question for your new questions.  I went ahead and edited my post to reflect what you can do.  I believe that should work.  However, I strongly believe you really should look into what @vittore suggested.

Comment: @silvesterprabu , watch this video https://education.10gen.com/courses/10gen/M101/2012_Fall/courseware/Week_4_-_Performance/Efficiency_of_Index_Use/ and learn what .explain() does for queries

Answer (score 0):

regex will work perfectly fine. there is also good news for you as monogdb will be releasing full text search index in the upcoming version

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/#text-indexes